# R-Studio load time extremely slow

Tags: r, ide, rstudio, lag, rstudio-server

Opening files, sourcing files, even simple logical statements in the console such as, 2+2. These processes will often lag and take extremely long to finish. Any suggestions on how to speed up these processes?

Comment: Are you sure your computer doesn't have a problem with the RAM, for example ?

Comment: @MbrMbr I only have 4GB of RAM. So "memory.limit(size = NA)" is 3583. I guess this could be the reason for the lag?

Comment: The maximum amount of RAM doesn't mean much. 2 + 2 should easily fit in 4GB. What would be relevant is the amount of RAM that is used at the time when you are experiencing those lag spikes. Check this in task manager.